# Can qr code be read by any mobile camera?

Tags: android, qr-code

Can I read any QRcode using mobile camera, if I implement the a program which will implement zxing library. Or is there something like, different specification for each code. Lets say I am implementing a program to create a QR code and he who needs to read this code needs to know my specifications, or his reading program has to know my specifications?

Comment: what do you mean by specification?

Comment: QR codes have only one format. Any Android phone that has a camera and can run a QR app can read the codes. What that phone can do with the code has nothing to do with QR.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini : so if I make a qrcode from some data and send the image to anyone or make a print of it, anyone can read it using their mobile camera?

Comment: YES. Even on iPhones and iPads.

Comment: Yes you can ready any QR code using any camera (as long as it can get a clean read), it's all down to the software.

@MathewFoscarini is right. There are some specifications (look it up if you want to conform to the standard): limits on how many bits can be stored, error correction, 3/4 corners use a square pattern for orientation, and depending on the size, another square pattern is used for tracking.

There's probably an ISO spec out there (https://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/), but I'd use pre-existing solutions (XZing is good) to save yourself the trouble

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

1. **Specification:** There is no difference in specification for formats (now they are stable)
2. **Camera:** Cameras without auto-focus cannot (or find it difficult to) scan a QR Code

> **Note:**
>
> 1. There is no official specification for this -- the QR code spec
>      does not say anything about the contents. Everything I know about the
>      commonly-used and de facto formats and conventions is summarized in
>      this wiki: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents
> 2. Most cameras these days have autofocus

Comment: kindly click on the check mark against the answer if you used this information